# Could not write file ink_sparkle.frag.spirv

Tags: flutter, dart

Could not write file to `F:\codecanyon-33776097-handyman-service-flutter-ondemand-home-services-app-with-complete-solution\handyman_mainfile_sourcecode\Mobile app\provider-handyman app\provider\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag.spirv`

**Run time Error**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1915 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Could not write file to F:\codecanyon-33776097-handyman-service-flutter-ondemand-home-services-app-with-complete-solution\handyman_mainfile_sourcecode\Mobile app\provider-handyman app\provider\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag.spirv

Target debug_android_application failed: ShaderCompilerException: Shader compilation of "G:\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\shaders\ink_sparkle.frag" to "F:\codecanyon-33776097-handyman-service-flutter-ondemand-home-services-app-with-complete-solution\handyman_mainfile_sourcecode\Mobile app\provider-handyman app\provider\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag" failed with exit code 1.
impellerc stdout:

impellerc stderr:
Could not write file to F:\codecanyon-33776097-handyman-service-flutter-ondemand-home-services-app-with-complete-solution\handyman_mainfile_sourcecode\Mobile app\provider-handyman app\provider\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag.spirv





FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'G:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1297

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'G:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I try All possible solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.